# Android Studio - How can I open url in User.java?

Tags: android-studio

I'm new in android studio.

I'm hope to open url with User.java(has been data-binding), but the code is not working.

Could someone give some advice?

Thanks

Edit: OpenURL method is called in activity_main.xml
Edit: I have found problems.

**User.java**

```
public class User {

    Context context;
    String url;

    public User(Context context, String url) {
        this.context = context;
        this.url = url;
    }
    public void OpenURL() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        User user = new User(getApplicationContext(),"https://www.google.com.tw/?hl=zh_TW");
        activityMainBinding.setUser(user);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.rl.mp_a.User" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="@string/button"
            android:onClick="@{() -> user.OpenURL()}"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Seems like you are not calling OpenURL method.

Comment: I do call method in activity_main.xml

Comment: please add how you are calling in activity_main.xml.

Comment: ok
i have added in post